# Dynamic sized array of pairs: Setting values for first/second

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting errors "subscript requires array or pointer type" when working with an array of pairs. I've looked at all the other threads with similar problems, but have been unable to resolve it.

I dynamically declared an array of pairs which looks like:

```
pair<T, int> *m_Array;
```

And set the array size with:

```
m_Array = new pair<T, int>[c];
```

Now what I am failing to do is access the first and second of the pair, in an index of the array. I get the error when I try to do things like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_Size; i++) {
    m_Array->first[i] = rhs.m_Array->first[i];
    m_Array->second[i] = rhs.m_Array->second[i];
}
```

It intuitively seems like it should be more like the following code, but my IDE does not like me having `m_Array[i]`

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_Size; i++) {
    m_Array[i]->first = rhs.m_Array[i]->first;
    m_Array[i]->second = rhs.m_Array[i]->second;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about _"my IDE does not like"_.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

If `m_Array` is a pointer to some pairs, then `m_Array[0]` is the first pair; then `m_Array[0].first` is the "first" member of that first pair.

There is no need for the dereferencing member access operator `->`, as the subscription `[i]` has already dereferenced for you (that is, `m_Array[i]` means `*(m_Array + i)`). So you just need the normal member access operator`.`.

So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_Size; i++) {
    m_Array[i].first  = rhs.m_Array[i].first;
    m_Array[i].second = rhs.m_Array[i].second;
}
```

Or you could skip all this trouble and just write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_Size; i++) {
    m_Array[i] = rhs.m_Array[i];
}
```

Or you could skip that too and change from `new` and arrays to a nice `std::vector`, then have it do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I did not go with that previously was because when I would type `m_Array[i].` it said that no members were available, and it had no auto-complete option. I use Visual Studio, so in general if there is no auto complete option it means that it is no good.

Comment: @Grehgous: You should use brain first, Intellisense/autocomplete second (or not at all). Relying on tools like this is a bad idea as they are not perfect